# Search a pdf file and append a string to the filename

Tags: shell-script, grep, pdf

I have several PDF files that all contain the string "R E A D I N G n n", where n n is the number of the corresponding reading. There is exactly one space between every character, i. e. " R E A D I N G 1 0".

I would like to write a bash script to search every file for the number n and append that number at the beginning of the file. For instance, if the script finds "R E A D I N G 1" in the name.pdf, it has to rename the file name to 1.name.pdf, etc.

How to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question depends on whether this string can only appear *once* or multiple times in the PDF file(s) considered.
Assuming it can occur only once, **and** the string in question is contained as actual text (i.e. not only in graphical form) the following approach, which requires GNU Awk and the external tool `pdftotext`, should work (the example is for a single file passed as parameter):

```
#!/bin/bash

OLDNAME="$1"

NUMBER="$(pdftotext "$OLDNAME" - | awk '/R E A D I N G/ {match($0,"R E A D I N G ([[:digit:]])( [[:digit:]])*",a); gsub(" ","",a[2]); print a[1] a[2];}')"

NEWNAME="$NUMBER.$OLDNAME"
mv "$OLDNAME" "$NEWNAME"
```

The `match` function of `awk` checks for the existence of a specific pattern and outputs the "actual value" of the pattern to the output array `a`, where the entries `a[0]` contains the entire found pattern and `a[1]` to `a[n]` contain the "actual values" of any sub-expressions enclosed in parentheses in the pattern, in our case the "number part" `([[:digit:]])( [[:digit:]])*` in array entries 1 and 2 (cf. e.g. the [GNU Awk User's Guide section on "string functions"](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#String-Functions)). If the result is a single-digit number `a[2]` will remain empty, which doesn't matter. Because in the two-digit case the space between the digits will also be matched, we use `awk`'s `gsub()` function to remove it in the two-digit case.

In order to apply it to several files, you can modify the script as follows and then pass an entire list of PDF files as argument (like `./rename.sh *.pdf`).

```
#!/bin/bash

for OLDNAME in "$@"
do
    NUMBER="$(pdftotext "$OLDNAME" - | awk '/R E A D I N G/ {match($0,"R E A D I N G ([[:digit:]])( [[:digit:]])*",a); gsub(" ","",a[2]); print a[1] a[2];}')"

    NEWNAME="$NUMBER.$OLDNAME"
    mv "$OLDNAME" "$NEWNAME"
done
```

Comment: I found out that there are spaces between every character in the string, i.e. "R E A D I N G 1 0". The string " R E A D I N G" (with spaces between characters) appears two times, but only one time followed by a single or double digit. On the other hand "reading" and/or "Reading" is found many times in the file. I think, there should be an amendment in the script.

Comment: I see. And is there also a space between the digits in the "double digits" case? Is there exactly one space in between the individual characters of "READING"? Is there exactly one space between the keyword "READING" and the number?

Comment: YES. There is only one space between every character in "R E A D I N G 1 0"

Comment: Ok, then I will edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: Please also change your original question in order to reflect the _actual_ format of the string you are looking for, so that others may better understand why I included the `sed` step in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly. Appreciate!

Comment: You're welcome! If you found the answer useful, please consider accepting it so that others facing a similar problem may find it more easily.

Comment: if the PDF contains the "R E A D I N G n n" string more than once, it doesn't matter.  use `head -n 1` to get only the first.

Comment: Also, and this is extremely important:   **double-quote your variables**.  Always.  Every time you use them.   This includes `$@`, which should **never** be used bare, it should **always** be used with double-quotes, as `"$@"`.   And double-quote command-substitution too.    Any time there is a chance of unwanted word-splitting, you need to use quotes.

Comment: I've added double-quotes to your answer where they are needed.